# Unable to renew SSL certificate using certbot

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, cert

I'm trying to renew my SSL certificate in my AWS EC2 server, but I'm getting the following error so after a lot of research I couldn't find the solution.

The command I run:

```
$ sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

Error:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mydomain.com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for mydomain.com
Using default addresses 80 and [::]:80 ipv6only=on for authentication.
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain mydomain.com
http-01 challenge for mydomain.com
Cleaning up challenges
Attempting to renew cert (mydomain.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/prod-mydomain.conf produced an unexpected error: Some challenges have failed.. Skipping.
All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

All renewal attempts failed. The following certs could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: mydmain.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: 2.211.168.8: Invalid response from
   http://mydoamin.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/ov6EBHInETwkZZ-oqLNI908jFXvN7PFK86ZCJYcdrtA:
   404

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just added the certs and you are testing the renewal process, you will need to restart the webserver to activate/apply the new certs before you attempt to renew.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I use `default` as a filename inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder. After I changed it to `yoursite.com`, where yoursite.com is you site address. The `sudo certbot renew --dry-run` started to work fine.
Maybe it helps to somebody:

```
# Rename file
cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
mv ./default ./yoursite.com
# Update certs, don't forget to replace yoursite.com with your address
sudo certbot --nginx -d yoursite.com -d www.yoursite.com
# Check nginx config
nginx -t
# Restart nginx to apply certs
sudo systemctl reload nginx
# Check renew
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error given, you need to ensure that the domain that you are trying to create the certificate for is pointing to the server.

You probably need a `A` DNS entry for `mydmain.com` pointing to your server IP.

I believe this is how LetsEncrypt ensure ownership of the domain.
https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/